# CSV to CSV datamapper in mule

Tags: mule

I am trying to transform one csv file to another one using mule.

But how I want is for example I have 4 header in the source csv file,

heade1, header2, header3, header4

And client may pass only first 3 header and its value in the csv file. I am getting error if mule datamapper does not find all the header in source csv.

```
    Parsing error: Unexpected end of file in record 1, field 2 ("test2"),
 metadata "headertest"; value: '<Raw record data is not available, 
please turn on verbose mode.>'
```

How can I set the datamapper to work if source file does not contains all the header/values

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a clean way to do that yet, but you could add a pre process step that adds a field separator at the end of each line in the input csv (i.e. add a comma at the end of each line).
This way the last field will be assumed empty.
HTH,
Marcos